# If a subset of R is lebesgue measurable, cane we show that its product with R is measurable in R2?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A\subset \mathbb R$. A is Lebesgue measurable if and only if $A \times \mathbb R$ is measurable in $R^2$.

All my attempts seem to rely on Borel sets. I am kind of stumped on how to do this more generally.

EDIT: I figured out the reverse direction, but the forward direction is still confusing me!

Here is how I showed the reverse direction:

Let $A\subset \mathbb R$, and assume that $A\times \mathbb R $ is Lebesgue measurable. For any subset $E \subset \mathbb R^2$ we denote
$\{E_x = x\in \mathbb R:(x,y)\in E\}$
$\{E_y = x\in \mathbb R:(x,y) \in E\}$

Now we construct $\mathcal A$ to be the collection of all E such that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are measurable in $\mathbb R$. Below, we show that $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

If $E=\phi$ both $E_x$ and $E_y$ are measurable (value zero) and so $\phi \in \mathcal A$

If $E_y$ and $E_y$ are measurable in $\mathbb R$then they are closed under countable unions and therefore E is closed under countable unions

By measurability the the compliments of $E_y$ and $E_x$ exist in $\mathbb R$ and therefore the compliment to E exists in $\mathcal A$

Hence $\mathcal A$ is a sigma algebra which contains all rectangles, and must contain all measurable subsets in $\mathbb R^2$.
Now if we set E to be equal to $A\times R$, then $A\times R$ must be measurable, and by construction $E_y=E_0=A$ must be measurable.

EDIT 2: Possible forward direction

To prove the forward direction assume A is lebesgue measurable. There exists an open set $U_1$ and closed set $V_1$ such that $U_1 \supset A \supset V_1$ and $\lambda^*(U_1\setminus V_1) < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$. Now consider the following Cartesian products: $U_1\times \mathbb R$, $A\times \mathbb R$, $V_1\times \mathbb R$. Let $U_2 \in \mathbb R^2$ be the open set generated by  $U_1\times \mathbb R$, and let $V_2\in \mathbb R^2$ be the closed set generated by $V_1 \times R$. Then we have that  $U_2 \supset A\times R \supset V_2$, and $\lambda^*(U_1\setminus V_1) < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$. Thus $A\times R$ is lebesgue measurable.

Comment: So you figured out : "$A \times \mathbb R$ is measurable in $\mathbb R^2$ , implies that $A$ is measurable in $\mathbb R$", is this direction correct? Please tell us how you figured it out, and  which results you used.

Comment: I think that you can prove it using only the definition of Lebesgue measure set.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I am over thinking the forward direction.

Comment: I think I figured out the forward direction too. Ill post it in an edit

Comment: What does it mean for a closed set to be generated by another set?

Comment: Well an arbitrary intersection or countable union of closed sets is closed, correct? Maybe I should have been more explicit about the construction of V2, but I was running out of time. I think its possible though!